# Assertions over multiple views in Espresso

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I want to make an assertion with Espresso over several views. For example, I want to check that all the rows of a listview are checked, and I don't want to check each row one by one (I could have 100 items in my list). So, can I do something to perform an assertion over multiples views? I cant't find the way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` holds only certain amounts of views, not to the number of data you have provided. At time you can have, let's say 10 items displayed and 90 not displayed.

1. You should get item count in with onData();
2. Iterate from `0` to `itemCount` perform scrolling to that position
3. Assert for each view `atPosition(index)`

Comment: Actually that is what I'm doing right now. Inside a for, I scroll over the list and perform an assertion. But I would like to do something like assert that all the checkboxes in each row of my list view are checked, avoiding to check each row one by one inside a for...

Comment: @VictorManuelPinedaMurcia You'll still need to iterate over the views. If you somehow save the check state to the model, then you'll still need to iterate over the items.